# How to create D3 svg element in drag and drop method

Tags: d3.js, svg

I am have a pallet section using html and SVG canvas.I want to create SVG element when click a button and paste it in to SVG in drag and drop method.my pallet section i creates like this

```
<div id="toolbox">
      <input id="task-button" type="image" title="Activity" src="img/rec.png" alt="Activity">
    </div>
```

I create SVG element like this when button click

```
d3.select("#task-button").on("click", function(){
var sampleSVG = svg;
       sampleSVG.append('rect')
       .attr('id', 'task'+(++idtaskelement))
          .style("stroke", "black")
          .style("stroke-width", "2")
          .style("fill", "white")
          .attr('transform', 'translate(' + d3.event.pageX + ',' + d3.event.pageY+ ')')
        .attr("rx", 10)
         .attr("ry", 10)
          .attr("width", 120)
          .attr("height", 80)
          .on("mouseover", function(){d3.select(this).style("fill", "aliceblue");
var point = d3.mouse(this)
  , p = {mx: point[0], my: point[1] };
console.log(p.mx +"and "+ p.my);
        })
          .on("mouseout", function(){d3.select(this).style("fill", "white");})
          .on("click", function(){
            tmodal.style.display = "block";
          })
          .call(drag)
    });
```

This element have drag functionality i created like this.

```
var drag = d3.behavior.drag().on('drag', function(d) {
   dragMove(this)
 })
function dragMove(me) {
   var x = d3.event.x
   var y = d3.event.y
   d3.select(me).attr('transform', 'translate(' + x + ',' + y + ')')
 }
```

Is there way to call Drag function and start dragging after button click and when we click in canvas we can paste it in the canvas.
If there any way to do this functionality please let me know.

[image]

Comment: Did you find any clue?